Teoplitz like theorem
Let
$$
{a}_{11}\\
{a}_{21}\; {a}_{22}
\\
{a}_{31}\; {a}_{32}\; {a}_{33}
$$
satisfy
(i) for fixed $k, \mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}{a}_{nk} = {a}_{k}$ exists;
(ii) $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{k = 1}}^{n}{a}_{nk}$ exists, say equals $A$;
(iii) $\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{k = 1}}^{n}\left| {a}_{nk}\right|  \leq  M < \infty, \forall n \in  N$.
Prove that if $\left\{  {x}_{n}\right\}$ converges to $x_0$, then $\mathop{\lim }\limits_{{n \rightarrow  \infty }}\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{k = 1}}^{n}{a}_{nk}{x}_{k}$ exists.
My attempt: 1. The limit seems to be $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k x_0$. But $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ I do not know exists, since I could not take limit in $A-\epsilon<\sum_{k=1}^n a_{nk}<A+\epsilon$.

If we do not see the limit, use the Cauchy's criterion then . But how to estimate $|\sum_{k=1}^n a_{nk}z_k-\sum_{k=1}^m a_{mk}z_k|$. The third condition seems useless here...even though I know it is not superfluous.


The lemma below is an adaptation of Fatou's lemma:

Lemma. If $(b_{n,k})$ is a double sequence of non-negative real numbers, then
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k} \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{n,k}. $$

Let us first demonstrate how this lemma can be used to resolve OP's question. Let $a_{n,k} = 0$ for $k > n$. Then the assumptions on $(a_{n,k})$ can be rephrased as:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n,k} = a_k$ for all $k$,
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n,k} \to A$, and
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_{n,k}| \leq M$.

From this and the lemma,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_{n,k}|
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_{n,k}|
\leq M. $$
Hence, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|$ converges absolutely. Now, fix $K \geq 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
&\left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk} x_k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x_k \right| \\
&\leq \left| \sum_{k=1}^{K} (a_{nk} - a_k) x_k \right|
+ \left| \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty} a_{n,k} (x_k - x_0) \right|
+ \left| \sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty} a_{k} (x_k - x_0) \right| \\
&\leq \left| \sum_{k=1}^{K} (a_{nk} - a_k) x_k \right|
+ 2M \left(\sup (|x_k - x_0|)_{k > K} \right)
\end{align*}
Taking $\limsup$ as $n \to \infty$, this gives
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{nk} x_k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k x_k \right| 
&\leq 2M \left(\sup (|x_k - x_0|)_{k > K} \right)
\end{align*}
Since the left-hand side does not depend on $K$, letting $K \to \infty$ shows that the limsup vanishes. Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

Proof of Lemma. Let $c_{n,k} = \inf_{m \geq n} b_{m,k}$. Then $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{n,k} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{n,k} $ holds for all $n$. Hence
$$ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{n,k}
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_{n,k}. $$
However, since $c_{n,k} \geq 0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{n,k}$ is non-decreasing in $n$,
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{n,k}
= \sup_{n\geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_{n,k}
= \sup_{n\geq 1}\sup_{K \geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{n,k}.
\end{align*}
Since we can always interchange the order of two suprema,
\begin{align*}
= \sup_{K \geq 1} \sup_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k=1}^{K} c_{n,k}
= \sup_{K \geq 1} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \liminf_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k}
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n\to\infty} b_{n,k}.
\end{align*}
